# A good workflow for creating websites and deploying them ?

Tags: apache, web, deployment, web-deployment

I currently have a portable apache, mysql and php server zip that I extract for each website that I work on, and when I want to upload the files i just do it over ftp to the server.

Is there any sort of program that would automate the process of getting started with a new project? Like I could just click a button, it would create+run its own 'sandboxed' webserver , and then through options or something it could automatically copy a basic smarty (templating engine) setup or somehow manage packages so that I could always be on the latest version of jQuery, html5boilerplate, etc

I know things like ansible exist for linux which make it easier to get things set up on multiple servers.. but I was wondering if there was some sort of smaller scale for the average developer?

Am I stuck to just copying and pasting files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the limited information you gave and assuming this is to be deployed to a Linux server I would recommend the following things:

1. get rid of the zip file
2. install php, php modules, apache and anything else through the package manager (apt/yum)
3. use a server side package manager for web applications like bower to install things like jQuery.
4. pull out any application specific configuration you have into a separate area/directory structure.  I assume this will be different for each project
5. put the configuration into github
6. use the new github repository as a basis for customization via Ansible.  Ansible playbooks exist to make things easier for the average developer.  You can easily write a playbook to install all necessary software packages, configure the packages and deploy your application (even easier if it's in github since there are ansible git modules)

With a well crafted ansible approach you can use the same set of playbooks for deployment and updates.  You will also get the benefit of ensuring your deployments are all in sync from a configuration perspective.

This answer could be further expanded given more exact requirements